# Plain-text formatted report into Crystal Reports

Tags: parsing, crystal-reports, report, string-formatting, plaintext

I have these plain-text reports.  Can I please have some suggestions on what general approach to use to get these into crystal reports?  Can I parse the file within CR? Do I need to script outside CR and re-write to a different format?  I'm new to CR, and if there's a different software that would be better for this I'm open to that.  The end-goal is to transform these reports into a nicely formated pdf with company logo, a few graphics, styled table, etc.

You can see the file contains data fields that I would need to capture such as account number, name etc.   But then also a variable length table with headers.

Example report: (This is the exact format, with just identifying information changed)

```
                      MY REPORT                                      Page:  #
10/18/17                                                             09:44 AM

ACCOUNT NUMBER : 456789
COMPANY NAME   : JOHN DOE
ADDRESS        : 8001      ANYWHERE DR
                 SOME PLACE, USA
SYSTEM TYPE    : MAXMODEL9000

  ID        EVENT TYPE               DESCRIPTION
----------  ----------------------   --------------------------------
    3       TYPE 1                   BLAH BLAH
    4       TYPE 1                   BLAH
    5       TYPE 1                   BLAH BLAH BLAH
    6       TYPE 2                   DR
    7       TYPE 3                   KITCHEN
   11       TYPE 3                   SOMETHING
   12       TYPE 4                   SOME DESCRIPTION
   13       TYPE1                    TEST
```

Comment: what is the database format and which database are you using?

Comment: What I've been tasked with is working from the generated reports in the format above.  The system generating the reports is legacy and only generates reports in that format.  It recently moved from in-house to cloud-based by the vendor.  There's currently no API for the software, and no direct access to the database.

Comment: So instead of giving access to database you have been provided with the report and you need to develop the same in crystal report from this report?

Comment: To my knowledge it is easy if you get the access to the database instead of report. You can use the design of the report and generate the report from data in database

Comment: @Siva  Yes.  I'm working on getting access to the database, but if that's not possible (even though we own the data... it's the vendor we're fighting here), is there a general approach you could suggest to first analyzing the text file to extract the data, and then either importing that into CR or re-writing the file so it can be used like a database?

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to convert the report in to excel format and then use that excel as the datasource to generate the report... But here thee will be one excel created for one report. If you start creating like this there will be one connection for one report and if you need to avoid this then you need to merge all excel files to one excel file again this is like a digging in reverse direction. In this case you can't guarantee the data to what extent it is correct.